# create entity - google app engine - most convenient way?

Tags: google-app-engine, entity, jdo

whats the most simple way to create a new entity in google app engine? i used now a simple servlet form, but it is annoying to upload a project only because you want to create a new entity. i am using eclipse with java. ( creating entities is documented on google only for python )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the admin console - in production, at http://appengine.google.com/, or on your development server at http://localhost:8080/_ah/admin/